# Unable to retrieve Squid OID information for monitoring proxy

Tags: centos, proxy, squid, snmp

I installed **Squid** and **snmp** on my CentOS 7 virtual machine and now I would like to monitor the proxy server using snmp.
The problem is that I cannot retrieve (by the `snmpwalk` command) any of the available Squid OID under the **1.3.6.1.4.1.3495** parent tree. See this link for the entire collection: [Squid Wiki](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Snmp#Squid_OIDs)

For instance, if I prompt the command:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <machine_ip>:3401 .1.3.5.1.4.1.3495.1.1.2.0
```

which is supposed to retrieve the cacheSysStorage, I get a "NO Response" error. I even tried the following alternative prompts:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <machine_ip> OID_number

snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost:3401 OID_number
```

So with or without the 3401 port, it does not matter: it always results with a timeout error.
Looking at the `snmpd.conf` file, I saw that another OID tree is getting some system information, so I prompted the following:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <machine_ip> .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.100
```

I get a positive response! But it is not the OID tree needed for monitoring the Squid proxy server.

FYI, I edited the `snmpd.conf` file with the following:

```
proxy -v 1 -c public <machine_ip>:3401 .1.3.6.1.4.1.3495.1
```

and I double checked that the public zone in FirewallD service has the port **UDP 3401** allowed.
I think to have tried any possible action but I am still unable to test OID information retrievement.

Could you suggest me anything to check or modify?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like an incorrect configuration setting of the `squid.conf` file.
For anyone in the future would come here...

I setup the access control properties by using Webmin (Servers > Squid proxy server > Proxy restrictions): I had allowed the `snmp_community` called public (which is the one I use) but this created a **http_access** allow rule in the configuration file instead a **snmp_access**, as written here: [`http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Squid.+The+definitive+guide/Chapter+14.+Monitoring+Squid/14.3+Using+SNMP/`](http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Squid.+The+definitive+guide/Chapter+14.+Monitoring+Squid/14.3+Using+SNMP/)

Now I am getting the information correctly.
Thank you.